# How does the find command search for files

Tags: linux, shell, find

Quarrying out from another thread [Move file that has aged x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818508/move-file-that-has-aged-x-minutes/58819809?noredirect=1#comment103925943_58819809), this question came up:

How does the `find` command found typically in Linux search for files in the current directory?

Consider a directory that contains a fairly large amount of files, then:

Firstly `find MY_FILE.txt` returns immediately and secondly `find . -name MY_FILE.txt` takes much longer.

I used `strace -c` to see what happens for both and I learned that the second command invokes a directory scan, which explains why it's slower.

So, the first command must be optimized. Can anybody point me to the appropriate resource or provide a quick explanation how this might be implemented?

Comment: Despite being not really useful, in the thread I referenced, people used `find` on a single file to find out if the file is older than e.g. 10 minutes.

Comment: The `find` command is in the [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for find is `find <paths> <expression>`, where *paths* is a list of files and directories to start the search from. find starts from those locations and then recurses (if they're directories).

When you write `find . -name MY_FILE.txt` it performs a recursive search under the `./` directory. But if you write `find MY_FILE.txt` then you're telling it to start the search at `./MY_FILE.txt`, and so it does:

```
$ strace -e file find MY_FILE.txt
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "MY_FILE.txt", 0x556688ecdc68, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
(No such file or directory)
: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Since the path doesn't exist, it only takes a single system call to determine that there's no such file. It calls `newfstat()`, gets a `No such file or directory` error, and that's that.

In other words, `find MY_FILE.txt` isn't equivalent to `find . -name MY_FILE.txt`. Heck, I wouldn't even call it useful because **you're not asking it to search**. You're just asking it to tell you if `MY_FILE.txt` exists in the current directory or not. But you could find that out by simply calling `ls MY_FILE.txt`.

Here's the difference:

```
[~]$ cd /usr
[/usr]$ find . -name sha384sum
./bin/sha384sum
[/usr]$ find sha384sum
find: ‘sha384sum’: No such file or directory
```

The first one performs a recursive search and finds `/usr/bin/sha384sum`. The second one doesn't recurse and immediately fails bcause `/usr/sha384sum` doesn't exist. It doesn't look any deeper. It's done in a nanosecond.

Comment: I see, so it is a single system call. I would then have to look for the implementation of this `system call`  to see how it actually works I guess.